# Custom Authenticator in Android

Tags: android, android-authenticator

I am learning Android Authenticator and want to implement my own custom Authenticator by following this [post](http://blog.udinic.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/).
At some point in the tutorial, it says:

> The authentication will be against a Parse.com account that I created for this cause.

1.Does this mean that the authToken will by provided by this parse.com ?
2.Is there any other websites/server where I can authenticate my users ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer on your first question is - yes - parse.com will used as server to authenticate your user.
The answer to your second question - a lots of. But I doubt that someone will give you a free unlimited web-services. You need to write your own authenticator server-side and host it on internet.

Comment: Thanks sir. Could you please share some website that would provide me free limited access to authenticate my user ?  I just wanna use it for testing purpose.

Comment: https://www.rcdevs.com/demos/ this has a demo version. Just Google it. We implemented our own, because in security you should not trust noone

Comment: Does all user authentication mechanism provides authentication-token upon successful authentication ? And would it be correct to say that Android authenticator only relies on those mechanism which provides auth-token ?

Comment: no, it may be otp or even fingerprint. It just "validating the user identity". In simple words this object ensures that the user who want to use some network services is the user who has the specified android device. It is the "something I have" pattern in security means.